# Environment variables fail to set in cron task

Tags: python, linux, environment-variables, cron

I am attempting to install a new cron task on a server.  I am able to run the process via command line, but cannot run it via cron.  This is due to environment variables for PATH and PYTHONPATH not being set correctly when the task is run via cron.  (I am actually having this trouble with all cron jobs on the server, but am focusing on one process in this question for simplicity's sake.)

Here is the cron entry for the process:

`### procmon NLite ###
*/2 * * * * . ~/.bashrc; cd /var/networkip/nlite/proc_mon; . bashrc; cd bin; ./proc_mon.py > /dev/null 2>&1`

Now, bashrc in the proc_mon directory contains:

```
BASEDIR=$PWD
KODIAK_ROOT=$BASEDIR/
BASEPATH=$KODIAK_ROOT

pathadd PYTHONPATH ${BASEDIR}/lib
```

So, when the cron task is run - PYTHONPATH *should* be reset, but this is not happening.

There are several other older servers successfully running these procs via cron.
Solutions attempted thus far:

- compared all bashrc or bash_profiles from a successfully running the cron task to the server failing to run crons
- logged environ variables to confirm this is the issue

Solutions I am not interested in:

- a cron task to set environmental variables.  There are several procs that need to run via cron and all have different PATH and PYTHONPATH variables relative to that specific script.  Doing this could get very messy and is just not a good long term solution as I install the same procs and crons on future servers.

Further info:

- Linux distro for server failing cron: CentOS release 6.8
- Linux distro for server with cron success: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.2 (Tikanga)

Since the crons is able to work on other servers, there must be a reasonable solution to the problem.  I am also on SuperUser, so mods please let me know if the question is better suited to that platform.

Comment: Update: environment variables are actually NOT the problem.  Cron appears to be running in POSIX mode.  When `set +o posix` is added to the beginning of a cron tasks, the proc runs successfully.  But still need a more global solution...

Answer (score 1):

You need to `export` your variables in your `bashrc` for them to be seen by the python process:

```
BASEDIR=$PWD
export KODIAK_ROOT=$BASEDIR/
export BASEPATH=$KODIAK_ROOT

pathadd PYTHONPATH ${BASEDIR}/lib
export PYTHONPATH
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but please read my question fully.  I am running the exact cron tasks on several other servers and am having no issues with the others.  I clearly state I am aware of the "solution" you provided, but not interested in it as not only is it cumbersome for future server builds with the software I am installing, but there are several cron tasks running on the server, all with different environment variables relative to that specific script.